# checkBox once at the time in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to select one checkbox at a time in order to setState with a specific value, the problem is that I am not sure if I need to loop over all the checkboxes and un-select the one that I didn't click.

in my case here I am using the value `value="Fanny" | value="Abed"` in order to identify which checkbox i cliciked

```html
  const [check, setcheck] = React.useState(false);
  const [checkBoxValue, setCheckBoxValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [info, setInfo] = React.useState(null);
 
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (check && checkBoxValue === "Abed") {
      setInfo("Abed");
    } else if (check && checkBoxValue === "Fanny") {
      setInfo("Fanny");
    } else {
      setInfo(null);
    }
  }, [check, checkBoxValue]);



return (   <label>
              <input
                value="Abed"
                type="checkbox"
                defaultChecked={check}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setcheck(!check);
                  setCheckBoxValue(e.target.attributes.value.value);
                }}
              />
              Abed!
            </label>
            <label>
              <input
                value="Fanny"
                type="checkbox"
                defaultChecked={check}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setcheck(!check);
                  setCheckBoxValue(e.target.attributes.value.value);
                }}
              />
              Fanny!
            </label>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: If you want only one to be checkd, you should use a radio button instead of a check box.

Comment: the problem with the radio button once you select one it will stay selected, so in this case, i need a way to un-select!

Comment: You can unselect a radio button too if it is controlled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be. If only one checkbox should be checked, then ultimately that means you only have *one* value. Meaning you only need to keep track of that value. E.g.:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Foo = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(null);
  const toggle = evt => setChecked(current => current === evt.target.value ? null : evt.target.value);

  return (
    <>
      <label>
        <input
          value="Abed"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked === 'Abed'}
          onChange={toggle}
        />
        Abed!
      </label>

      <label>
        <input
          value="Fanny"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked === 'Fanny'}
          onChange={toggle}
        />
        Fanny!
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
```